# Mongo DB Merge to return only single field

Tags: mongodb

Frinds
I have the following Mongo DB query to select a random record and return the updated record using merge

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "lastAccessed": {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sample": {
      "size": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      tableName: "myTable",
      lastAccessed: "$$NOW"
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

***the return of above query is***

```
[
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "lastAccessed": ISODate("2022-02-16T13:20:38.968Z"),
    "tableName": "myTable"
  }
]
```

**However I want to tweak above query and return only *tableName* instead , please let me know how it can be done ?**

Comment: only myTable if possible ?

Comment: yes that is needed , Thank you

Comment: you can project table name and get `[{"tableName": "myTable"}]` . Im not sure if possible to get just a value

Comment: ok then how to get only [{"tableName": "myTable"}]

Comment: `{
    $project: {
      tableName: 1,
      lastAccessed: 0,
     _id: 0
    }
  }`  add this part to the pipelne after merge

Comment: Below is throwing an error  {
    $merge: {
      into: "collection",
      on: "_id",
      whenMatched: "replace"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      tableName: 1,
      lastAccessed: 0,
      _id: 0
    }
  }

Comment: remove the `lastAccessed: 0` part and try. it should do

Comment: Yes it works , could you add it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$project` in your aggregation pipeline to show/hide the fields you want.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "lastAccessed": {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sample": {
      "size": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      tableName: "myTable",
      lastAccessed: "$$NOW"
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  },
  {
     $project: {
      "tableName": 1,       
      " _id": 0      
    }   
  }
])
```

will give
`[{"tableName": "myTable"}]`

Comment: `$merge can only be the final stage in the pipeline`. How are you doing this?

Comment: @Kobato good question to which unfortunately i dont have an answer. i only tested this in mongoplayground and im not sure if it ignores the merge stage there.